# Python не видит значений таблицы sqlite

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Есть кусочек кода:

```
cur.execute(f"UPDATE subjects SET summ = summ + 5, kolvo = kolvo + 1\
                 WHERE title = 'Кошка'")
```

Также есть простая таблица, где есть строка, у которой title = 'Кошка'.
Вот сама таблица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но питон выводит ошибку:
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Кошка
При этом считывать значения из таблицы получается. Как это исправить, чтобы и записывать значения тоже было можно?
Заранее большое спасибо, буду рада любой помощи!
cursor() подключен

Код работы с таблицей:
(код в классе, поэтому self)

```
self.con = sqlite3.connect("marks.sqlite")
cur = self.con.cursor()
subjects = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM subjects").fetchall()# это работает
cur.connection.commit() # не сработало
cur.execute(f"UPDATE subjects SET summ = summ + 5, kolvo = kolvo + 1\
                WHERE title = 'Кошка'")
```

Comment: В `sqlite` изменения нужно сохранять, сделайте `connection.commit()`

Comment: Такая же ошибка(

Comment: Весь свой код покажите, который к изменениям в бд относится

Comment: Добавила в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот здесь всё работает с т.з. sqlite3

то есть, коммит в текущей сессии для селектов не важен, но обязателен по выходу, если там нет автокоммита в настройках

вот здесь посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142531/sqlite3-operationalerror-no-such-column
и тут [Как устранить ошибку "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: ..."?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1374647/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-sqlite3-operationalerror-no-such-column)

еще версия - проблема в используемых кодировках (utf, win)

```
import sqlite3


con = sqlite3.connect("marks.sqlite")
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("DROP TABLE subjects")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE subjects(title, summ, kolvo)")

cur.execute("""
    INSERT INTO subjects VALUES
        ('Кошка', 1975, 8),
        ('НеКошка', 1971, 7)
""")

subjects = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM subjects").fetchall()# это работает
print(subjects)

cur.execute(f"UPDATE subjects SET summ = summ + 5, kolvo = kolvo + 1\
                WHERE title = 'Кошка'")
#cur.connection.commit() # не сработало


subjects = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM subjects").fetchall()# это работает
print(subjects)
```

**/bin/python3.11 /py.2/stack.py

[('Кошка', 1975, 8), ('НеКошка', 1971,7)]

[('Кошка', 1980, 9), ('НеКошка', 1971, 7)]**

Answer (score 1):

В базе данных `sqlite3` после открытия транзакции с помощью `INSERT` или `UPDATE` нужно зафиксировать транзакцию с помощью `connection.commit()`. Можно делать сразу несколько изменений и потом единожды их фиксировать.

```py
self.con = sqlite3.connect("marks.sqlite")
cur = self.con.cursor()
subjects = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM subjects").fetchall()
cur.execute(f"UPDATE subjects SET summ = summ + 5, kolvo = kolvo + 1\
                WHERE title = 'Кошка'")
self.con.commit()
```

Comment: Попробовала Ваш вариант - увы, но нет. Python сам столбец не видит

Comment: Ваш код прекрасно работает на только что идентичной созданной таблице, ошибка где-то в классе, вероятно

Comment: Но компилятор указывает ошибку именно на эту строку. А если ее убрать - то все прекрасно работает

Comment: Значит вы подключаетесь не к той базе данных, пытаетесь обновить данные не в той таблице

Comment: Тогда почему считывать данные получается из этой базы получается?

Comment: Может у вас 2 похожих базы/таблицы, одна из которых была для тестов, я же не знаю. Ваш код работает, это факт.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что у меня была переменная в строке `f("{}")`. А когда я попробовала вставить в `title` просто строку ("Кошка") тоже сработало, так как до этого создалась пустая таблица из-за ненайденного значения в f-строке.
Нужно было удалить пустую таблицу и запрос записать как `title = '{переменная}'`
Также нужно не забыть закоммитить.